I have Arducam IMX708 camera, I am unable to connect it to raspberry pi
I bought arducam IMX708 camera. I have connected it to Raspberry pi 4B+. i followed https://docs.arducam.com/Raspberry-Pi-Camera/Native-camera/12MP-IMX708/ document. performed everything correctly. however, i could not able to detect the camera. I used vcgencmd get_camera command in terminal it shows, supported=1, detected=0 , libcamera interface=1. what to do? I have also tried this with raspberry pi3. but same output is shown. if I used libcamera-hello in cmd terminal, it streams the video.

The camera appears to be advertised to work with all Raspberry Pis but it wouldn't hurt to add that information to the question. Also a picture might help. If, for nothing else to check if the ribbon cable looks to be installed correctly (not backwards) and is well seated. If it is suppose to work, perhaps it is time to try different hardware. Do you have another Raspberry Pi you could try?

Under Raspberry Pi OS Bookworm (current with all updates), this camera is supported without using any of the Arducam software. Put the following in your /boot/firmware/config.txt:
camera_auto_detect=0
dtoverlay=imx708

(By default, camera_auto_detect is set to 1 to detect Raspberry Pi Ltd's camera modules.)
The camera should be listed when you enter the rpicam-still --list-cameras command.
The vcgencmd get_camera command only works with the old camera system, which is no longer supported. You have to use picamera2 now.

oh, I see you're using Bullseye ... As this is a clone of the Raspberry Pi v3 camera that never(?) worked under Bullseye, I don't think you'll have much luck

I am using Raspb /Linux 11 (bullseye). libcamera-hello gives live stream.

that would suggest it is being detected. vcgencmd likely won't work with the new camera stack, and the old camera commands are gone. Maybe try libcamera-still --list-cameras?

The line Start_x=1 I made it comment. Then it worked. And yes, vcgencmd command dose not work with latest version of Raspbian. Libcamera command was helpful. It worked
